# How to implement a Dictionary with two keys?

Tags: c#, .net

Using C#, I'd like to find a way how to implement something like a dictionary that depends on two key objects.

I have an object and a string. To this two values I want to assign one double value. So what structure should I use? Or how can I implement such a structure?

Comment: Do you want to lookup by each key separatedly? If yes, then it nulifies most answers already given.

Comment: Do you need both the object and string to form a unique key, or is the object a unique key, and the string another unique key, and you want to be able to look up the value using either key?

Comment: @Euphoric and Ben Voigt I need both objects to form the unique key

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could have a custom class which aggregates the two properties, override the [GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) method on it and then have a `IDictionary<CustomClass, double>`.

Comment: Thanks. I always tried it with overriding equals. I thought in Java this is used to compare.

Comment: You *always* need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` together so they are consistent. If they are not consistent the dictionary will become buggy.

Answer (score 18):

Try to use something like that

```
Dictionary<Tuple<object,string>,double>
```

Comment: I didn't realize .net 4.0 added tuples, no more using KeyValuePair when needing to have a tuple of 2 objects!

Comment: in 4.0 aslo is pretty nice thing as anonymous classes var temp = new { value1 = 2 ,value2 = "some string"} for temporary usages

Comment: @Stecya C# 3 actually has anonymous types

Comment: @RichK can you explain that in more detail? Im using .net 3.5 as I should have stated maybe

Comment: @Roflcopter I'm not sure anonymous types will help you with your problem I was just letting Stecya know that they're not exclusive to C# 4. If you want to learn more about anonymous types there are plenty of resources online to guide you.

Comment: Anonymous types won't help here since they have no name and thus you can't put them as type parameter into Dictionary. There are a few hacks based on generic inference that can work around that, but they are no good idea in this context.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using .NET 3.5 you can't use Tuples, because those were added in .NET 4.

But you can easily create class, that will contain both of your keys and that can be used as key in a dictionary. Only things to do is to override [Equals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals(v=VS.90).aspx) and [GetHashCode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=VS.90).aspx) methods in your key class, so Dictionary can use it as a key correctly.

Those should be implemented logicaly by equating or hashing both of your keys. And some more related information : [GetHashCode vs. Equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overriden-in-c).

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need to. If your object has overridden the GetHashCode member of Object.

```
Dictionary<string, double> myDict = new Dictionary<string, double>();

myDict[myObj.GetHashCode() + myString] = myDouble;
```

Comment: With .net hashcodes it's kind of an iffy implementation. I've used this technique before with unique userids along with MD5 hashes (hexadecimal string) of files. It works much better when the two strings being concatenated are of an expected length since that kills the possibility of a collision.

Comment: Completely broken. If two objects have the same HashCode they will get the same string-key and thus share a dictionary entry.

Comment: Objects that have the same HashCode would cause collisions even if you used just the object all by itself since the default comparer for Dictionaries relies on GetHashCode.

Comment: The difference is that with the standard dictionary a collision means only a slight slow down(unless very many collide, in which case it will be a big slow down) but doesn't affect the correctness. With your code a collision means a bug.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Are strings treated differently than other objects?

Answer (score 2):

Create a class to be your key:

```
public class MyKey
{
    public String Str;
    public Object Obj;
}
```

Then:

```
Dictionary<MyKey, double> MyDict = new Dictionary<MyKey, double>();
```

Comment: That doesn't work without overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` since by default classes use referential equality.

Comment: It might work if you used a struct instead. But I didn't look deeply into the default implementation of struct equals.